# GZIP content in Google App Engine using django-nonrel

Tags: google-app-engine, gzip, django-nonrel

I have a django-nonrel app running in Google App Engine and am wanting all the content to be gzipped.

I keep reading that GAE automatically gzips the content but when I check the headers using Firefox's web developer toolbar I get the following result:

```
Via: 1.1 TL-ISA1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expires: Thu, 09 Dec 2010 12:23:46 GMT
Date: Thu, 09 Dec 2010 12:23:46 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Etag: "463ad22512f09050f76a291c11d9746d"
Server: Google Frontend
Last-Modified: Thu, 09 Dec 2010 12:23:46 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0

200 OK
```

I was expecting to see **Content-Encoding: gzip**, but since it is not there, my assumption is that the content is not being gzipped as it should.

Am I missing something? For example, do I need to do something extra if I am using django-nonrel?

Just to add, I am new to Web development - so don't be afraid to patronise. Thanks

Comment: are you requesting the page through a proxy?

Comment: Ah yes. I think that was it. Odd that other sites are appearing gzipped but not this one. Just tried from outside a proxy and it does seem to work. Can you rewrite as an answer and I can mark it as accepted. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gzip should work out of the box, you are probably requesting the page through a proxy.